# InnerHTML not working on external Java Script file

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript external file code:

```
document.getElementById("not-working").innerHTML=person.firstname+person.nickname+person.lastname+"is"+"awesome.";
```

I am trying to write the `innerHTML` in my HTML document by writing the above in my external Java Script file but it's not working.

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>       
        <script src="home.js"></script>
   
        <p id="demo">
            Hello, this is Maqnoon.
            
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
        </p>
        <p id="hello"></p>
        <p id="not-working"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any error in your browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: Perhaps you have to wait until DOM is loaded. You don't can be shure, that if you put the SCRIPT-TAG at the end of your HTML, that  than the DOM ist ready.
Perhaps a init Function in your external js will help. And than you call this with window.onload = () => {init();}
Use console.log to debug, when you call your init.

Answer (score 0):

Put your external JS importing `<script>` tag right after the ending `</body>` tag. Also, put your JS codes inside of the DOMContentLoaded listener like this,

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
    function myFunction() {
        // ...
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

Explanation: The browser interprets the HTML from top to bottom, line by line. When you put the JS in the header section of the HTML, there is a possibility that your JS will finish running before the browser reaches to the elements in the later sections of your HTML. In that case, the JS will not be able to see the elements that are going to be loaded right after, maybe a few milliseconds or nanoseconds later. This is why it is advisable to put the `<script>` tags after your `</body>` element so that by the time the browser reaches to the JS, the HTML elements are already loaded.
To take it a step further, there is the 'DOMContentLoaded' event which is fired by the browser when it finishes loading the HTML. So, we put our JS code in it to make sure that the code runs after the entire HTML is loaded and available.

Comment: Would be helpful to clarify the *why*s so that OP can learn what was wrong in their approach.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//The external js code
const obj = document.body.getElementById("ye");
obj.innerHTML = " Hello";
```

```html
<!--This my html page that connect to external javascript file -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Scrapping</title>
</head>

<body>
<p >Hello We are webscrapping</p>
<p id="ye"></p>
</body>

<script type="text/JavaScript" src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: When external js is added at the bottom this happens.The html run html code line by line so when it get to the script tag   after the body  then it run.